# How to Erase All Data on Compaq Laptop

Tags: compaq-laptop

I'm selling my Compaq Presario CQ60 laptop, and I want none of my data associated with it.

So how do I do the above?

Comment: Have you done any research or tried anything? When you do not homework people aren't likely to help you. What's Operating System are you running? Did you get discs when you purchased the PC? Do you have the capability of burning a disc?

Comment: In response to your questions:

Comment: I have HP as my operating system. No, I did not get any discs when I purchased the item, as it was second-hand. Since I don't have the disc(s), I don't have the capability of burning them either.

Answer (score 0):

Options:

- If you have Windows 10 use the reset option in Settings.
- Use the recovery discs that possibly came with the PC.

  - Look for a 'recovery' or 'backup' Compaq or HP software that might be loaded on your PC & open it. When you're in it you should have an option to burn recovery discs (you'll need blank CD or DVD's). While disc 1 is inserted & from a fresh power-on tap a key when it prompts you to (else you may have to press a F9, F10, F11, or F12 to get a boot menu to select the CD drive)
- Use F12 (or F9, F10, F11) to boot into recovery environment to factory reset

Comment: If you have a self-encrypting SSD, you can also do a secure erase that deletes the encryption key and invalidates all other data.

Answer (score 0):

now i assume you have an unchanged copy of an original compaq modiffied windows installation with the hp settings and whatever (i reinstalled a different os in my compaq i cant remember what the og tools were called) but if thats the case then turn off your compaq then turn it on and spam esc then press on the key corresponding to the hp repair then follow the steps and your done if you dont have that option you have to donwload a windows iso image like windows 7 (go to youtube if you need help with that) then flash it on a usb then go to the bios settings (by turning off and pressing the esc key then pressing the key corresponding to bios then go and change the boot order to make usb boot first before the hard drive then just do the simple setup) (also watching a tutorial on yt on how to reinstall windows "7 for example" will be much helpful because VIDEO ya know)